# Call subscribe method inside the parent method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have written a generic method like this:

```
getArticleById(loading: Loading): void {
    this.articleService.getArticleById(this.data.definition.id)
      .map((res: any) => res.json())
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res.definition.is_purchased) {
          //more code
          } else {
            //more code
          }
          loading.dismiss();
        } else {
           loading.dismiss();
        }
      }, () => { loading.dismiss(); });
  }
```

Parent method (or calling) is like this:

```
 myParentMethod(){
     const loading = this.loader.create({
      content: 'loading...'
    });
    loading.present();

    this.getArticleById(loading);//can I call the `loading.dismiss()` here. 
    }
```

I would like to remove the loading parameter from the genric method(`getArticleById()`) and need to put that inside the parent method(`myParentMethod()`) after resolving the subscription.Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the observable terminating at the higher level, you'll need to return an observable that the higher-level function can access.

Try writing it like this:

```
getArticleById(loading: Loading) {
    const articles$ = this.articleService.getArticleById(this.data.definition.id)
      .map((res: any) => res.json());

    article$.subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res.definition.is_purchased) {
          //more code
          } else {
            //more code
          }
    });

    return article$;  
}
```

`finally` is a useful operator which

> Invokes a specified action after the source observable sequence terminates gracefully or exceptionally.

```
myParentMethod(){
    const loading = this.loader.create({
      content: 'loading...'
    });
    loading.present();

    this.getArticleById().finally(() => loading.dismiss());
}
```

However, this code is still structured a bit awkwardly. I'd separate out the logic to get the observable from that to handle it, and write the code as follows:

```
getArticleById(): Observable<Article> {
    return this.articleService.getArticleById(this.data.definition.id)
      .map(res => res.json());
}

handleArticle(article) {
    if (article.definition.is_purchased) {
      //more code
    } else {
        //more code
    }
}

myParentMethod(){
    const loading = this.loader.create({
      content: 'loading...'
    });
    const article$ = this.getArticleById();

    loading.present();

    article$
      .finally(() => loading.dismiss())
      .subscribe(article => this.handleArticle(article));
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what did you mean by `$` mark (i.e. `article$`)? Is that naming convention for an observable? I would like to know about it too? Any reference or like that? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a naming convention for observables.